# how to get the product of a tree in scheme

Tags: scheme, binary-tree

I am using scheme for the first time and I am trying to get the product of a tree for some reason when run my program I am getting this error:
1 ]=> (product t1)

;The object () is not applicable.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 2) => Specify a procedure to use in its place.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

here is my code:

```
(define (node x l r)   ; x is data, l is left, r is right
  (lambda (s)
    (cond  ((= s 0) x)
           ((= s 1) l)
           ((= s 2) r)
           (#t 'error))))

(define (data t) (t 0))
(define (left t) (t 1))
(define (right t) (t 2))

(define (size t) (if null? t) 0 (+ 1 (size (left t)) (size (right t))))
(define (product t) (if null? t) 0 ( * (data t)(product(left t)) (product (right t))))

(define t1 (node 5 (node 3 '() '()) (node 8 (node 7 '() '()) '())))
```

Comment: Why are you representing a node as a `lambda`? it'd be much easier to just use a list.

Comment: Learning to use lambdas to represent data is a pretty valuable experience, I think. For specific use cases there are more suitable data structures, such as a list, but lambdas are general enough that you can use it to model anything without needing to know about any specialized structures.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses inside the if statements are wrong.
if takes three arguments:

1 - an expression that evaluates true or false

2 - an expression to be evaluated if 1 is true

3 - an optional expression to be evaluated if 1 is false

for example:

(if (null? t)(execute-this-if-true)(execute-this-if-false))

and not

(if null? t)(execute-this-if-true)(execute-this-if-false)

When your code tries to evaluate the product of the empty list it gets to the if statement; null? evaluates to a function, which is considered a true value**, and then tries to evaluate (), which is impossible

** in scheme, anything but #f is true

I suspect there is also error in the algorithm; whenever it encounters an empty list it returns zero, and the product of anything by zero is always zero, so the program will always return zero. () should probably return 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define node
  (lambda (n ret)
    (if (null? n)
        (ret 1 false false)
        (if (integer? n)
            (ret n false false)
            (ret (cadr n) (caddr n) (cadddr n))))))

(define prod
  (lambda (n)
    (if n
        (node n (lambda (x l r) (* x (prod l) (prod r))))
        1)))

(define t1 '(node 5 (node 3 () ()) (node 8 (node 7 () ()) ())))

(display (prod t1))
```